# Converting certificate byte[] to X509Certificate in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate

I've stored a certificate as a Base64 encoded string in the database. I can read this  from the the database and decode it but I'd like to convert the decoded byte[] into a X509Certificate. I am looking for sample code to do this. I have tried:

```
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

This leads to an issue with the encoding type. A valid sample String or byte[] that represents a certificate will be good.

Any pointers will be great! Thanks.

Comment: What is the "issue with the encoding type" that you mention? Is it a database issue or a Java issue?

Comment: I suspect that what you need is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getEncoded%28%29. The getEncoded() method will return you a byte[].

Comment: How did you obtain the byte array? And what exactly is the issue with the encoding type? And which of these lines of code throws the exception? And what *is* the exception?

Comment: This question needs to be closed, not bumped to the home page. OP hasn't responded to queries about it in five years.

Answer (score -4):

Your sample code looks fine. You can generate that `byte[]` yourself using openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -outform DER -out cert.der
```

Comment: -1: OP states, "in Java"

Comment: I answered his Java specific question. It looks fine. I was addressing the second part of the question, where he's asking for samples: generate those with external tool openssl.

Comment: The OP mentions "issue with encoding type". Does your answer answer that question (not really sure what the question is myself!)? In what way is your openssl example relevant to the OP question?

Comment: I think that what the OP is looking for is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getEncoded%28%29. This will return him a byte[]. If this is correct then re-write your answer to indicate that method.

Comment: Look, he has a byte array that doesn't work with that code. Either his Java code is wrong or the input is wrong (not a certificate? different encoding? We don't know until we see the input or the error msg). I'm claiming his code is not the problem, I tested it with some samples, and I'm empowering him to generate sample inputs for testing.

Comment: You need to add your last comment to your answer.